# How to get the drawable from relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-viewpager, android-drawable

**What i have done:**
I have set the bitmap for a relative layout as below

```
RelativeLayout root;
root= (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),godImages[position], options);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),preview_bitmap);
root.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

---

**What i am trying to do:**
I am trying to get the bitmap from the relativelayout back again that was set
so that i can pass to another activity.

### ***`Note:`*** `i am aware of using the intents to padd data between activities only i want to know how to get the bitmap`

### Any ideas on How to achieve this ?

Comment: The last time you asked this, it was suggested that you save and pass only the Resource ID, then decode the Bitmap anew in the next Activity. This is still pretty much the best solution. Easiest way is probably to cache the ID in the layout's tag: `root.setTag(godImages[position]);`

Comment: @MikeM. .... i could pass the resource id but .. there is a catch ... i have used view pager to set a number of images .... i only want to pass the currently viewing image .... only way to do this is to get the image and pass it

Comment: @MikeM. .... one of the answers did answer my question .... but my root problem still remains ..........since view pager always loads two things(current-one,nxt one) ...... is there any way to access the current attributes of the view we are viewing ? ... hope i am clear

Comment: The `ViewPager#getCurrentItem()` method should help.

Comment: @Mike M.... This helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

**1.** Try:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**2.** Or try:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( layout.getLayoutParams().width, layout.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
layout.layout(layout.getLeft(), layout.getTop(), layout.getRight(), layout.getBottom());
layout.draw(c);
```

To get the current `ImageView`

**1.** To get current position, use

```
ViewPager viewPager = getView().findViewById(r.id.pager);
int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

**2.** To get the current `View`, use

```
View currentView = viewPager.getChildAt(int position);
```

This `currentView` is the `View` created by the `onCreateView()` method of the current `Fragment`.

**3.** To get the `ImageView`, use

```
ImageView currentImage = (ImageView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

where `R.id.image` is the `ImageView` object you want from the current `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks ... it did answer my question ... but my problem still remains. need an info: since view pager always loads two things(current-one,nxt one) ...... is there any way to access the current attributes of the view we are viewing ?

Comment: what do you mean "current attributes" ? And I believe that `ViewPager` loads either the current or all `Fragment`s depending on whether you use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or a `FragmentPagerAdapter` respectively ...

Comment: `current attributes` ... means ... if i use my usecase example , ...... as sson i load  my view pager .... the adapter 2 images .... (1st and 2nd) .... when you move to 2nd image .... third is also loaded ..( total there are three imgs) .......... meaning to say pager always keeps the next image ready ..... What i am trying to understand is to access the current displayed image regardless of other images(views) loaded

Comment: Thank you for Insightful  answer and clear info[+1] from me  :)